How to convert bytes to string in a list of dictionaries
I have a list of dictionaries like this:
list1 = [
    {'id': b'1', 'ip': b'1.1.1.1'},
    {'id': b'2', 'ip': b'2.2.2.2'}
]

How can I convert each value of the dictionaries within a for loop?
I first tried like this, but tuple does have no object assignment:
for x in list1:
    for y in x.items():
        y[1] = y[1].decode('utf8')
    print(x)

Would you please help me?

The tuple is a shallow-copy of the key/value pairing. Replacing values in the tuple (which you can't do, but even if you could) won't change the dict. Replace the original dict's value though, and it works just fine. Bonus: Unpack the result of .items() (it's not only more readable, it's faster than indexing repeatedly to boot):
for x in list1:
    for k, v in x.items():  # Unpack to key value pairs
        x[k] = v.decode('utf8')  # Replace value of key with decoded value
    print(x)

A dict comprehension could also be used, constructing a replacement dict. To reassign the elements of list1, you'd either need to nest it in a listcomp (which would get in the way of printing), or use enumerate (to have the index to reassign):
for i, x in enumerate(list1):
    # Reassigning x as well lets us print it without looking it up again
    list1[i] = x = {k: v.decode() for k, v in x.items()}
    print(x)


Note: UTF-8 is the default encoding used in Python 3, so as demonstrated in the second code example, you can omit it entirely and it will still work just fine.

Calling .items() yields a tuple of key and values.
If you want to just iterate over the values call .values() instead and then directly call .decode() on the value:
for x in list1:
    for y in x.values():
        y.decode('utf8')
    print(x)


Decoding without reassigning (and you can't reassign if you only have the value, not the key) is thumb-twiddling; the result is immediately thrown away, and nothing changes.

Yes, @ShadowRanger is right. I couldn't find the way to assign it to a variable or even the way to create a new list. I really am grateful for the answer.
